# How do I use a variable with a boolean value as a condition in an IF statement in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, boolean

How do I use a variable with a boolean value as a condition in an IF statement in JavaScript?

```
patt1 = new RegExp ("time");

var searchResult = (patt1.test("what time is it" )); // search for the word time in the string
                                                 // and return true or false

If (searchResult = true) // what is the right syntax for the condition?
{
    document.write("Word is in the statement");
    document.write("<br />");
}
```

Comment: you could use only the variable as the "condition": `if (searchResult)`, using one = won't work because the = operator is for assignment in java and jscript, if you want to use that syntax you should use `if (searchResult == true)`

Answer (score 3):

Simply use the value directly and Javascript will determine if it's truthy or not.

```
if (searchResult) {
  // It's truthy
  ...
}
```

The problem in your original sample is you are using `searchResult = true`.  This is not a simple conditional check but is instead an assignment which results in a value which is then checked as a conditional.  It's *roughly* the equivalent of saying the following

```
searchResult = true;
if (true) { 
  ...
}
```

In Javascript the `=` operator can be used in a number of ways

- `=` this is used for assignment
- `==` this is used for equality checking with coercion
- `===` this is used for strict equality checking

Comment: The larger point here is that the reason his code wasn't working is because he was using `=` to assign `true` to `searchResult` rather than comparing them using `==`.

Comment: @JustinSatyr updated answer to be more complete

Comment: And also `If` instead of `if`.

Comment: thanks for all your help guys, just started coding last and I guess I am still making basic errors.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (searchResult == true) {
...
}
```

This is a test.

Short version:

```
if (searchResult) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (searchResult) is the same as if(searchResult == true)
if (!searchResult) is the same as if(searchResult == false)
```